# Xcode single file size over 100mb cannot upload to github

Tags: ios, xcode, github

In my project folder i have a folder called appnameappversion ie: Facebook1.03 Inside the folder is .ipa file of the app. It is over 100mb and is the reason my project will not upload to github. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/153084/use-git-source-control-xcode-9) and added the standard swift gitignore, however i am still getting the error that the .ipa file is too large

here is my gitignore

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/swift,macos

### macOS ###
*.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon

# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk

### Swift ###
# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated
build/
DerivedData/

## Various settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata/

## Other
*.moved-aside
*.xccheckout
*.xcscmblueprint

## Obj-C/Swift specific
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.dSYM.zip
*.dSYM

## Playgrounds
timeline.xctimeline
playground.xcworkspace

# Swift Package Manager
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Swift Package Manager dependencies.
# Packages/
# Package.pins
.build/

# CocoaPods - Refactored to standalone file

# Carthage - Refactored to standalone file

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/source-control/#source-control

fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots
fastlane/test_output


# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/swift,macos
```

UPDATE 2 : I have tried some of the solutions here, however when I push i still get the same issue of the .ipa file being too large

Comment: Don't upload the `.ipa` file to GitHub. GitHub is not a file sharing service anyways. You can choose which files to add to git in Xcode or you can simply add the `.ipa` file to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the large .ipa file is already part of your local index. Remove it using `git rm --cached [file]`.